# How to Android http post to Node.js

Tags: android, node.js, http, post

I want to send a simple HTTP POST request from Android to a Node.js server.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Android code:

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://54.68.139.250/bscreateuser");

    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "hellomoto"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "pswd"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Node.js code:

```js
app.get('/bscreateuser', function(request, response) {
  process.stdout.write("Attempted to create a user.");
  bscreateUser(request.query.username, request.query.password);
  response.send('-- BS -- User Created! username: ' + request.query.username +
    ' password: ' +
    request.query.password);
});

function bscreateUser(username, password) {
  messageBody = 'create_user("' + username + '","' + password + '")';
  queueUrl = DAO_QUEUE_URL;
  // sys.puts("--- going for BS ---");
  sendSQSMessage(JSON.stringify(messageBody), queueUrl);
}
```

Comment: It appears that some people were able to answer your question without very much detail. In the future though, please include a detailed description of the behavior you're observing, rather than just describing what you're trying to do. Descriptions of undesired behavior are usually necessary to be able to help you.

Comment: I agree with @skrrgwasme. The question does not post the exact error that occurs. The answers were based on the most obvious mistake on the server side code that you have provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `node.js` code, you are using

```
app.get('/bscreateuser', ...
```

Instead, you need to use the post method

```
app.post('/bscreateuser', ...
```

And access the requested variables like this :

```
request.body.varname
```

Comment: Thank you!  That got me in the right direction.  
Sorry for the noob question

Answer (score 0):

You make route of GET it must has to be post if you are posting data

node Code

```
app.post(..
```

and parameter may get

```
request.body.username or request.body.password
```